# Meta Recruiting SQL -- Join Part 2

Tags: sql, sqlite

The following schema is a subset of a relational database of a grocery store chain. This chain sells many products of different product classes to its customers across its different stores. It also conducts many different promotion campaigns.

The relationship between the four tables we want to analyze is depicted below:

```
        +------------------+---------+         +---------------------+---------+
        | product_id       | INTEGER |>--------| product_id          | INTEGER |
        | store_id         | INTEGER |    +---<| product_class_id    | INTEGER |
        | customer_id      | INTEGER |    |    | brand_name          | VARCHAR |
   +---<| promotion_id     | INTEGER |    |    | product_name        | VARCHAR |
   |    | store_sales      | DECIMAL |    |    | is_low_fat_flg      | TINYINT |
   |    | store_cost       | DECIMAL |    |    | is_recyclable_flg   | TINYINT |
   |    | units_sold       | DECIMAL |    |    | gross_weight        | DECIMAL |
   |    | transaction_date | DATE    |    |    | net_weight          | DECIMAL |
   |    +------------------+---------+    |    +---------------------+---------+
   |                                      |
   |    # promotions                      |    # product_classes
   |    +------------------+---------+    |    +---------------------+---------+
   +----| promotion_id     | INTEGER |    +----| product_class_id    | INTEGER |
        | promotion_name   | VARCHAR |         | product_subcategory | VARCHAR |
        | media_type       | VARCHAR |         | product_category    | VARCHAR |
        | cost             | DECIMAL |         | product_department  | VARCHAR |
        | start_date       | DATE    |         | product_family      | VARCHAR |
        | end_date         | DATE    |         +---------------------+---------+
        +------------------+---------+


 /*
 PROMPT:
 -- The VP of Sales feels that some product categories don't sell
 -- and can be completely removed from the inventory.
 -- As a first pass analysis, they want you to find what percentage
 -- of product categories have never been sold.
 
 EXPECTED OUTPUT:
 Note: Please use the column name(s) specified in the expected output in your solution.
 +-----------------------------------+
 | pct_product_categories_never_sold |
 +-----------------------------------+
 |               13.8888888888888889 |
 +-----------------------------------+
```

They want to find what percentage of product categories have never been sold

I tried this solution:

```
SELECT Count(*) * 100.0 / (SELECT Count(*)
                           FROM   product_classes) AS
       pct_product_categories_never_sold
FROM   product_classes AS C
       INNER JOIN products AS P
               ON C.product_class_id = P.product_class_id
       LEFT JOIN sales AS S
              ON S.product_id = P.product_id
WHERE  S.product_id IS NULL
```

This is the result:

```
 pct_product_categories_never_sold 
 ---------------------------------
      37.9746835443038
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NOT EXISTS` to check for each product category if it has ever been sold. 
The result of `NOT EXISTS` is a boolean value evaluated as 1 or 0 on which you can aggregate with `AVG()`:

```
SELECT 100 * AVG (
  NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM products p INNER JOIN sales s
    ON s.product_id = p.product_id
    WHERE p.product_class_id = c.product_class_id
  )
) pct_product_categories_never_sold
FROM product_classes c;
```

See a simplified [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=0b629b476567eb95bbf6485655548cd4).

Comment: Hello Forpas! Thank you for the query, however, this query is returning:  pct_product_categories_never_sold 
-----------------------------------
                26.582278481012654

Comment: @AndersonTegami and what is the problem?

Comment: The expected output is: 13.8888888888888889

Comment: @AndersonTegami then you did not explain what you want correctly because as you can see in the demo I provide in my answer the percentage result is correct.

Answer (score 0):

The correct solution would be the following:

```
SELECT 100.0 * (1 - COUNT(DISTINCT product_category) / CAST((SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT product_category) FROM product_classes) AS FLOAT64)) AS pct_product_categories_never_sold
FROM sales s JOIN products p ON (s.product_id=p.product_id) JOIN product_classes pc ON (p.product_class_id=pc.product_class_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution could be:

```sql
SELECT 
1 - (
  COUNT(DISTINCT product_category) * 1.0 / 
  (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT product_category) FROM product_classes)
) AS pct_product_categories_never_sold
FROM sales
JOIN products ON products.product_id = sales.product_id
JOIN product_classes ON product_classes.product_class_id = products.product_class_id;
```